# How to remove specific string from output?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, asterisk

i have a node.JS script that prints the status of peers some how its prints undefined which is dont want to be printed on browser. It prints output as : undefined "Reachable" undefined undefined "Reachable" undefined undefined "Reachable" undefined. So is there any way in javascript though which i can remove the undefined from the output? My code for printing data is `

```
<body>
<div id="ami_data"></div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>

var socket = io();

socket.on('ami_data', function (data){
console.log(data);
var str = document.getElementById("ami_data").innerHTML  +=           JSON.stringify(data.peerstatus) + "\r\n";

});
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can create a new database or not depends on the database engine (MySQL, Mongo, etc) you are using first, which then needs support from the PHP library you are using to access the database engine. In addition, an engine like MySQL also has user specific controls over who can create new databases.

Answer (score 0):

To use mysql as an example you would do

```
$this->db->query("CREATE DATABASE ?",[$this->input->post('db_name')]);
```

You will have some headaches switching between the dB's on the fly. Why do you need to create them? Could you use a user specific table prefix to create a namespacing kind of thing?